# Keeping DNA sequence after changing FASTA header on command line

Tags: fasta, grep, multi-fasta, command-line

I have a FASTA header that looks like this:

```
>7c8250ef-c89f-4d42-9d48-12c8fe245fb2 runid=606f271fc97598006ba5a922136a2c304cef75a5 sampleid=Pool12-1 read=19008 ch=301 start_time=2021-07-03T08:48:18Z barcode=barcode01
```

And I am able to change it to the desired output here:

```
>7c8250ef-c89f-4d42-9d48-12c8fe245fb2_001
```

Using this command:

```
grep '^>' 001_old.fasta | cut -d ' ' -f 1,8 | sed '/^>/s/$/_001/' > 001_new.fasta
```

However it completely deletes the DNA sequence for that read and only outputs the names of the headers to the new fasta file:

```
>7c8250ef-c89f-4d42-9d48-12c8fe245fb2_001
>815440d5-e033-446c-b7dd-5fad4105184a_001
>d36a0fea-101d-4bd9-bee4-adec7fe4d43c_001
>38ca9eb8-bbd2-4d0a-ab06-79d134ad46f1_001
...
```

I think it has something to do with the `cut` command I'm using. I tried just doing 1 but that gave the same output so I figured if I included the 8th position of text after a space it would work but again no dice. If someone could help me to include the DNA sequence under the FASTA header in this new file that would be great.

Comment: Do yourself a favor and use Bipython for parsing and modifying FASTA files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `grep`, `cut`, `sed` pipeline could also be replaced with the following [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) command:

```
awk '/^>/ { print $1 "_001"; next }1' file.fa
```

The general syntax of an AWK command is `condition { action }` where `condition` specifies a condition or regular expression, and `action` specifies a block of code or set of commands to be run when the condition is met. Both `condition` and `action` are *optional*. Here, we use a regular expression to match lines beginning with a ">" symbol, and print the first whitespace-separated field followed by "_001". We then use `next` to skip the remaining actions and move to the next line, which avoids any further processing of the current line. The `1` on the end is actually another condition that always evaluates to true. Since there's no action associated with this condition, AWK performs the default action which is to print the entire line. This effectively prints all lines that do not begin with a ">" symbol.

Comment: thank you this worked perfectly! and thank you for the explanation too

Answer (score 3):

The problem is in the `grep` command you're using, which only sends the fasta file headers to the output. Here's my guess at what the commands in your pipeline do:

1. `grep '^>' 001_old.fasta` - extract lines starting with '>' from `001_old.fasta`
2. `cut -d ' ' -f 1,8` - assume file contains space-delimited records; extract only the first and eighth field from each line
3. `sed '/^>/s/$/_001/'` - in lines that begin with a '>', replace the end of the line with '_001'
4. `> 001_new.fasta` - write result out to `001_new.fasta`

Of all of these, I think only the `sed` and output parts are important, but it needs to be slightly modified to work as intended:

```
sed '/^>/s/ .*$/_001/' 001_old.fasta > 001_new.fasta
```

Assuming I've got the syntax right, this should search for lines beginning with '>', and replace everything from the first space up to the end of the line with '_001'.

I'm more familiar with perl, so here's a perl one-liner that should do the same thing:

```
perl -pe '/^>/ && s/ .*$/_001/' 001_old.fasta > 001_new.fasta
```

Comment: thank you so much! this makes a lot of sense to me as well.